# SQL query to find the id that only speak english?

Tags: mysql

Find all the id that only speak english i am unable to do this.
the first table is language

```
+------+---------+----------+
| Id   | User_id | Language |
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 |     111 | english  |
|    2 |     112 | hindi    |
|    3 |     113 | odia     |
|    4 |     114 | english  |
|    5 |     115 | english  |
|    2 |     112 | english  |
|    3 |     113 | english  |
+------+---------+----------+
```

2- second table user

```
+------+------------+-----------+
| Id   | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
+------+------------+-----------+
|    1 | sirjit     | bit       |
|    2 | jit        | bi        |
|    3 | ji         | bi        |
|    4 | i          | b         |
|    5 | it         | ba        |
|    1 | sirjit     | bit       |
|    2 | jit        | bi        |
|    4 | i          | b         |
|    5 | it         | ba        |
|    3 | ji         | bi        |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

here is my code:-

```
Select First_name,User_id 
from user inner join language 
on user.Id=language.Id groupby User_id 
having count(language)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Speaking only english* means that there is only 1 row for the user in table `language` and that row contains 'english' in the column `language`:

```
select u.id, u.First_name, u.Last_Name 
from user u inner join language l
on u.Id=l.user_Id 
group by u.id, u.First_name, u.Last_Name  
having count(*)=1 and max(l.language)='english';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where 
    exists (select 1 from languages l where l.user_id = u.id and l.language = 'english')
    and not exists (select 1 from languages l where l.user_id = u.id and l.language <> 'english')
```

With an index on `language(user_id, language)`, this should be an efficient approach, since it does not involve aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two `count` expressions - one to make sure the user **does** speak English and another one to count all the languages he or she speaks:

```sql
SELECT   first_name, last_name, user_id
FROM     users u
JOIN     languages l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, user_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1 AND
         COUNT(CASE language WHEN 'english' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Comment: i want that the id should only speak english like id 1 is only speaking english but while id 2 is speaking both hindi and english

Comment: @shubhasispadhi That's why we have a `count(*) = 1` condition - it means the user speaks only one language.

Comment: can you just explain me this line "COUNT(CASE language WHEN 'english' THEN 1 END) = 1" @Mureinik

Comment: @shubhasispadhi it counts the number of languages that are `english` - it's a trick to to make sure the user does speak English.